# Program similar to getharmony.net

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, software, tablature, songwriting

[getharmony.net](http://getharmony.net/) was a very **interesting web** page where you could get the notes of a song with *guitar through a spectogram* and **make a tab** to interpret it. Unfortunately it is down, but I would like to know if there is an alternative that offers the same tools or if this page has moved to another domain.

Demostration:

It should be noted that I have already tried some alternatives with *Capo for MacOS*, *yalp.io*, *guitaa.com* and *chordify*, but it does not give me the results that I expect, since the song that I put does not have chords, rather it is a plucking than the page or program interprets it as chords.

I appreciate any suggestions as I would like to extract the tab of a song.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Unfortunately, it's not a site for recommendations such as you ask, so the question will be closed before too long.

Comment: Excuse me, where could I post my question?

Comment: You could try [https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).